# ways to prevent your app from being impacted by Firebase quota limits

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What are the ways i use to prevent the limit or over pricing of my app, i am new in firebase many dev are experiences the over pricing data read or write , how can i prevent this

Comment: Which [limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [setting monthly budget](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#manage_spending). It helps you to manage your spending on your projects. Setting monthly budget notify you if you are already approaching the maximum limit or exceeding your planned costs for the month.

You can check this documentation to [setting up budgets and budget alerts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/billing/avoid-surprise-bills#set-up-budget-alert-emails)

Additional information:

- [Avoid Surprise Bills](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/billing/avoid-surprise-bills)

> Important: Firebase pricing plans apply to the entire project, not just to individual apps registered in the project. When you're determining which pricing plan is right for you, consider the usage from all the apps registered in the same project.

- [Understand Cloud Firestore Billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing)

> Documents informs you the information details when it comes to Cloud Firestore pricing. Indicates here the limitation and monitor the expenses in your Cloud Firestore.

Hope it helps